# How to set the iframe content height in my case?

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I am trying to setup the iframe content height through angular

I have something like

```
<iframe id='iframe' width='100%' height='600px' data-ng-init="init('iframe')" 
 src='http://test.com' />
```

in my controller

```
 $scope.init = function(id) {
            console.log($('#'+ id))  -> show my iframe
            var x= $('#'+ id)..contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            console.log(x) -> gives me undefined

            var y = $('#'+ id)..contentWindow;
            console.log(y) -> give me undefined too 
        }
```

How do I set the iframe content height through my controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the iframe height to `100%`, and wrap it in a parent div that you control as per any usual method (like css).

Comment: DOM manipulation should be done inside a directive instead. For a crude example, see http://plnkr.co/edit/KgrhJg7xKQqxm9pho4SH?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some observations from your code:

1. `ng-init` is not the equivalient of `$(window).on("load", function(){...})`, more information about `ng-init` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit . That's why you are getting `undefined` for `x` and `y`, because when that code is executed the iframe hasn't been loaded yet.
2. In angular is not a good idea to access the DOM from the controller, consider doing those sort of operations in a directive instead.
3. If you are starting with angularjs I would recommend you to try not to use jQuery.

In your case I think that what you want is to define a directive like `iframeSetDimentionsOnload` and set the height there. I will give you in example in a few minutes.

Your `iframeSetDimensionsOnload` directive:

```
yourApp.directive('iframeSetDimensionsOnload', [function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('load', function(){
            /* Set the dimensions here, 
               I think that you were trying to do something like this: */
               var iFrameHeight = element[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
               var iFrameWidth = '100%';
               element.css('width', iFrameWidth);
               element.css('height', iFrameHeight);
        })
    }
}}])
```

Use it like this:

```
<iframe iframe-set-dimensions-onload src='http://test.com' />
```

Comment: @FlyingCat please have a look at my latest update and let me know if that solves your issue. Thanks!

Comment: If I try to get the height in my console I get the error: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` When trying it with the directive the onload is never fired, a console.log before the event listener logs.

Comment: I'm getting the following error on this: `Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`.

Comment: @membersound That error has nothing to do with AngularJs or with this question. This is a common "[same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)" issue. Did you even try to google that error before assuming that this was an issue with AngularJs?

Answer (score 0):

If your `iframe` is:

```
<iframe id='iframe' width='100%' height='600px' src='http://test.com' />
```

Your controller can look something like:

```
AppName.controller('someNameCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.width = '100%';
    $scope.height = '600px';

    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
        $scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
        $scope.height = $window.innerHeight;
        console.log($scope.width, "x", $scope.height);

        // manuall $digest required as resize event
        // is outside of angular
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});
```

Then you can play with the style as a variable

```
<iframe id='iframe' ng-style="{ height: height, width: width }" src='http://test.com' />
```